# python expression with or statement

Tags: python

I see the below statement in the github link and would like to how this condition is executed. The right expression to the or checks for a condition but the left side is more of a assigment statement.

https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme/blob/30a29a4a9c1f355cdbd69e65a0f3aad6948f458d/labelme/canvas.py#L464

```
shape.fill = shape.selected or shape == self.hShape
```

Comment: You're getting the precedence wrong. This is an assignment statement, where the right side of the assignment is an or expression. Equivalent to `shape.fill = (shape.selected or shape == self.hShape)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, `shape.selected` is a boolean attribute, so the code is equivalent to this:

```
if shape.selected:
    shape.fill = shape.selected
else:
    shape.fill = shape == self.hShape
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the precedence wrong.<sup>1</sup>

This is an assignment statement, where the left side is the name `shape.fill`, and the right side is the `or` expression. It's not an `or` statement, where the left side is an assignment and the right side is a comparison.

In other words, it's equivalent to:

```
shape.fill = (shape.selected or shape == self.hShape)
```

And to avoid any other confusion, the `==` is evaluated before the `or`, so it's ultimately equivalent to this:

```
shape.fill = (shape.selected or (shape == self.hShape))
```

And hopefully you understand what that means.

---

The implicit precedence rules<sup>2</sup> for every operator, symbol, and keyword can be inferred by worked out by reading the syntax in the Reference Manual, starting from [Top-level components](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/toplevel_components.html) and working down through statements (simple and complex) and expressions. Or you can read the [Full Grammar specification](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) for a more concise but less explanatory version.

But since you're using Python, you might prefer to learn by experimentation rather than by manual. In that case, check out the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module:

```
>>> import ast
>>> statement = 'shape.fill = (shape.selected or shape == self.hShape)'
>>> print(ast.dump(ast.parse(statement)), annotate_fields=False)
("Module([Assign([Attribute(Name('shape', Load()), 'fill', Store())], "
 "BoolOp(Or(), [Attribute(Name('shape', Load()), 'selected', Load()), "
 "Compare(Name('shape', Load()), [Eq()], [Attribute(Name('self', Load()), "
 "'hShape', Load())])]))])")
```

OK, that may be a bit hard to follow, but there are some nice third-party libs that format the tree more clearly. It comes down to this:

```
Module
    Assign
        Attribute
            Name('shape')
            'fill'
        BoolOp
            Or
            Attribute
                Name('shape')
                'selected'
            Compare
                Name('shape')
                Eq
                Attribute
                    Name('self')
                    'hShape'
```

So, you can see that there's an assignment (`Assign`) where the left side is the attribution (`Attribute`) and the right side is the `or` expression (`BoolOp`).

---

<sub>1. Technically, there's no precedence going on, because `=` isn't even an operator in Python. But it's easier to think about it this way, and only a tiny bit misleading, and hopefully the next sentence clears it up.</sub>

<sub>2. Again, the only *explicit* precedence rules are those that apply to operators, which doesn't include the `=` in your example. So you have to work out how the statement will be parsed, effectively the same way the parser does.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The `or` operator binds less tightly than the `=` you see on the left. Adding some parentheses may make the situation clearer:

```
 shape.fill = ((shape.selected) or (shape == self.hShape))
```

The parentheses I've added don't change anything in how the statement is evaluated. The two arguments to `or` are `shape.selected` (which is presumably a `bool`), and the expression `shape == self.hShape`. The result of the `or` expression is what gets assigned to `shape.fill`.

Answer (score 1):

It is evaluating the same sort of statement you would see in an `if` statement.

They are creating a boolean and assigning it to `shape.fill`. Presumably, `shape.selected` is either `True` or `False`. They are then applying a logical `or` with another boolean statement `shape == self.hShape`.

In the end, it is of the form

```
shape.fill = (boolean variable) or (boolean expression)
```

while evaluates to a boolean.